# Cross check the format of dates

Tags: r

Below code converts to a date format that is fine. But is there a way to cross check which format `dates` is there.

```
dates <- c("05/27/84", "07/07/05")
betterDates <- as.Date(dates,
  format = "%m/%d/%y"
> betterDates
[1] "1984-05-27" "2005-07-07"
```

Expected output

```
#### Format of dates. If I want to check what was the earlier format of dates. I should get below output
"%m/%d/%y"
```

Comment: In general, no, there is no way.  For example, `10/11/22` could mean either 10th November, 2022, or 11th October, 2022.

Comment: If you know the year of your data, you can narrow down to two unknown fields, then look at all candidates for one of the two that clearly shows day-of-month (over 12). This is of course only useful if all dates are in the same format, and you know something solid about some of them.